# Lightweight Podcast listener (Mac)

Tags: macos, mac, osx-snow-leopard, podcasts

I'm not a huge fan of iTunes and don't use it apart from listening to one podcast that's released several times a week.

Could someone please recommend me a lightweight Podcast listener for the mac so I don't have to deal with iTunes any more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many hours scouring the internet I haven't been able to find an alternative, so it looks like I'll have to use iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Juice](http://juicereceiver.sourceforge.net/). A bit about the app, from the website:

> - Juice is free
> - Juice supports more than 15 languages
> - Juice supports multiple media players
> - Juice is free software licensed under the GPL (open source)
> - Juice's primary purpose is to manage podcasts
> - Juice has a built-in directory with thousands of listed podcast feeds
> - Juice has auto cleanup, authentication, centralized feed
>     management and much more
> - Juice is accessible for blind and visually impaired users (windows
>     version only)

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never, check out www.podgrasp.com.

App Store link: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/podgrasp/id530928805?ls=1&mt=12

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is what you are looking for, but [Miro](http://www.getmiro.com/) is a podcast player as well, podcasts don't seem it's main focus though. It is an alternative to iTunes.

Answer (score -1):

All podcasts have an RSS feed. If you subscribe to the RSS feed—whether in Mail, Safari or any other RSS reader—then open the file in QuickTime each time the feed is updates, you have a pretty lightweight (but comparatively complex) system for listening to podcasts.

Comment: yes but I'd like something that does it all where I can input a feed URL if I have to but that's about it.